# Video on hover without loop

Tags: css, html, video, hover

So, i've managed to put a div with a video as background but you only see the video when you hover the div.

It's all working fine and this is the CSS i'm using:

```
.row .col .background-inner{
    background:url('https://meivcore.pt/novo/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/mecanica-small-filtro.jpg');
}

.row .col .background-inner .video{
    display:none;
}

.row .col .uncoltable:hover .video{
    display:block;
}
```

What is hapenning (as expected) is that i hover the div and the video keeps playing on loop. Is there anyway to remove this loop? I would like to hover the div, watch the video only once and stop on the last frame.

Comment: `.row .col .uncoltable:hover .video{
        background:url('https://meivcore.pt/novo/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/mecanica-small-filtro.jpg');
}`
**AND**
`.row .col .background-inner .video{
    background: none;
}`

Comment: @tipsfedora Please dont post answers as comments.

Comment: i'm not sure if it works, and i'm scared to death of receiving negative marks on my answer.

Comment: Make sure your `<Video>` tag doesn't have `loop` inside of it. The hover should have nothing to do with looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for a html5-video tag to loop is the loop attribute in the html5-tag.

I made a short codepen to show the markup difference:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQvvQw

The only difference between the two is the loop attribute at the end of this line:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay loop>
```

Ressources:
[MDN - HTML  Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

PS: It's pretty hard to find a definitive answer without a working demo of the problem.